# How to limit selection in more than one checked list boxes?

Tags: c#, selection, limit, windows-forms-designer, checkedlistbox

In C#, for one `checklistbox` I found the following to be good enough:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
 {
if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked && checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count >= 3)
    e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
 }
```

But I have many check list boxes and I want to implement different limits on all of them.  For example I want to limit my `checkedListBox1` to only 3 item selections, while `checkedListBox2` will be limited to 2 item selections and so on...

I tried making multiple `checkedListBox_ItemCheck` methods but none seem to affect the rest of the checklistboxes.  It only affects my first one.  Can anybody can help   me?

Thanks so much, I'm just beginning working with Windows forms.

Edit:  I hope this will make it more clear what I'm aiming to do:

say I have the following `checkedListBoxes`:  `checkedListBox1, checkedListbox2, checkedListBox3`

Here's what I'm trying to do:

`checkedListBox1 = (/*limit the number of items users are able to select to only 3 items*/);`

`checkedListBox2 = (/*limit the number of items users are able to select to only 2 items*/);`

`checkedListBox3 = (/*limit the number of items users are able to select to only 4 items*/);`

Comment: so you have a checkedListbox and you want to limit your users to be able to only check a limitted number of checkboxitems in those?

Comment: I have several checkedListBoxes and I want to make a function to limit the selection for different checkedListBoxes.  For example:  (checkedListBox1 = limit number of item selected to 3 items only);  (checkedListBox2 = limit number of item selected to 2 items only); (checkedListBox3 = limit number of item selected to 4 items only); etc....

Comment: let me know if this works for you, i tested it and it worked in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to achieve this, you can make the following `Method`:

```
       public void LimitCheckedListBoxMaxSelection(int maxCount, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == maxCount)
            {
                if (!checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex))
                    e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
            }
        }
```

then to use it, you would have to call the method in the `ItemCheck` event of the `CheckedListBox`.
first parameter is the limitation you want to enforce, i.e the max number of checked items allowed.
second parameter is the `ItemCheckEventArgs` from the control's event, which is named `e` by default.

**However**
you can also make a `delegate` and tweak the `Method` a bit more to make it attach an `ItemCheck` event to your `CheckedListBox` by doing the following:

```
 public void LimitCheckedListBoxMaxSelection(CheckedListBox checkedLB, int maxCount)
 {
     checkedLB.ItemCheck += (o, args) =>
     {

         if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == maxCount)
         {
             if (!checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex))
                 (args as ItemCheckEventArgs).NewValue = (args as ItemCheckEventArgs).CurrentValue;
         }
     };

 }
```

and then in order to use this you would have to call this method in your form's `Load` event and pass the `CheckedListBox` you want to limit to the method like this once per `CheckedListBox` :

```
 private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     LimitCheckedListBoxMaxSelection(checkedListBox1, 3);

 }
```

Comment: Hi!  Sorry for getting back kinda late.  I figured that my problem was because I was missing the "this.CheckedBoxtList....." line of code in my designer file.  But I learned a lot form what you posted.  I'll try to keep it in mind the next time I work with windows forms.  Thanks again! :)

Comment: @5120bee im glad I helped ! :)